# SQLITE. Update mulptiple columns with CASE expression

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 counters. If callback data is positive number comes, I increase the likes counter by 1, if negative, I increase the dislikes counter by 1, respectively. But my current code throws a syntax error.

```
cursor.execute("""
UPDATE posts SET
likes_count = CASE WHEN (?) > 0 THEN
likes_count = likes_count + 1 ELSE likes_count END
dislikes_count = CASE WHEN (?) < 0 THEN
dislikes_count = dislikes_count + 1 ELSE dislikes_count END
WHERE id = ?""", (data,abs(data),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("""
UPDATE posts SET
    likes_count = CASE WHEN (?) > 0 THEN likes_count + 1 
                       ELSE likes_count 
                  END,
    dislikes_count = CASE WHEN (?) < 0 THEN dislikes_count + 1 
                          ELSE dislikes_count 
                     END
    WHERE id = ?""", (data,data,abs(data),))
```

Each field update statement must resolve to a single value, your case statement cannot *do* anything except return a single value.
Simply remove the assignment inside your case statement, and the rest is valid.

`THEN likes_count = likes_count + 1 ELSE …`
Should be 
`THEN likes_count + 1 ELSE …`

Then you must separate each field update statement with a comma `,`.

Finally, note that you must pass through a parameter for each `?`. There are 3 `?` in this script, so you'll need 3 inputs.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. I copied this code and got the following error,
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "dislikes_count": syntax error`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the comma :), I've updated the response

Comment: Yes, I too figured out this via following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Just tried to escape double case and implement through `else` (or at least to escape double else), but it is both impossible :)

Comment: I don't have anything setup to test this script, but looks like you need to provide an additional input parameter as well